# Inverse image of $\tan(x)$.

Tags: functions

Let $f(x) = \tan(x)$.

What is $f^{-1}[\mathbb{R}^+]$?
(i.e. what is the inverse image of the positive real numbers under $f$?)

Would it just be the positive values of the domain of $\tan(x)$, i.e. the set
$$\{\text{$x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ : $x \neq \dfrac{\pi}{2} + k \pi$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$}\}?$$

Comment: Hint: You're looking to describe the set of real $x$ for which $\tan(x)$ is defined and positive.

Comment: Right. So, it's simply the interval (0, pi/2)?

Comment: No, there are many other points too. (Hint: Periodicity.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought initially. Wouldn't that be what I have in the original question, though? As in, the values {pi/2, 3pi/2, 5pi/2, ...} ?